# How to disable parameter name hints in the Visual Studio 2022 editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

How can I disable the editor parameter-name text which has started to show since a recent update? In this array example "index:" is shown.

[image: Sample of VS2022 code]

Answer (score 3):

This is called "Inline Hints" in Visual Studio. You can customize which are shown by going to

Tools Menu > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > "Inline Hints" group

[image]

Turn the setting on and off as you like. In your particular case, you're looking for the "Show hints for indexers" option.